Проверка даты рождения, если меньше 6 лет в 1с
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПоступлениеСпортсменаПриИзменении(Источник)
    
    Если Источник.ИмяПоля = "ДатаРождения" Тогда
        Если НЕ ПроверитьДатуРождения(Источник.ДатаРождения) Тогда
            ВызватьИсключение "Дата рождения спортсмена должна быть не младше 6 лет.";
        КонецЕсли;
    КонецЕсли;
    
КонецПроцедуры  

&НаКлиенте
Функция ПроверитьДатуРождения(ДатаРождения) Экспорт
    
    Если ДатаРождения = Неопределено Тогда 
        Возврат Ложь;
    КонецЕсли;
    
    Возраст = ТекущаяДата() - ДатаРождения;
    ВозрастВГодах = Год(Возраст) - 1899;
    
    Если ВозрастВГодах < 6 Тогда 
        Возврат Ложь;
    КонецЕсли;
    
    Возврат Истина;

КонецФункции


Конфигурация самописная или на основе БСП?
